# "Unacceptable content-type" when creating contact via Java client of sendinblue API

Tags: java, sendinblue

Really strange as I copy paste the code sample from the [sendinblue API doc](https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#createcontact):

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,"\"updateEnabled\":false,\"email\":\"example@email.com\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("api-key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The response is:

```
response code is: 406

response message is: Not Acceptable

response body is: {"code":"not_acceptable","message":"Unacceptable content-type"}
```

I use this Java client:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sendinblue</groupId>
    <artifactId>sib-api-v3-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Media type (= content type) is different between header and body. Both should use _application/json_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `content-type` in as JSON (application/json).

Comment: weird that it is not in the official doc.